# Collision Response method

Tags: java, math, graphics, game-development

Hi I try to implement a simple Sphere collision detection algorithm as explained here: http://wp.freya.no/3d-math-and-physics/simple-sphere-sphere-collision-detection-and-collision-response/

So I implement the method to check if Collision occurs:

```
private boolean advancedSphereSphere(Sphere a, Sphere b) {

Vector2D s = a.getPos().sub(b.getPos());
Vector2D v = a.getVelocity().sub(b.getVelocity());

float r = a.getRadius() + b.getRadius();

double c1 = s.dot(s) - r*r;

if(c1 < 0.0) {
    timeToCollision = .0f;
    return true;
}

double a1 = v.dot(v);
if(a1 < 0.00001f) {
    return false;
}

double b1 = v.dot(s);
if(b1 >= 0.0) {
    return false;
}

double d1 = b1*b1 - a1*c1;
if(d1 < 0.0) {
    return false;
}

timeToCollision = (float) (-b1 - Math.sqrt(d1) / a1);

return true;
}
```

Then I have a onDraw method that loops to draw all necessary elements, like this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    flowPhysics(false);
    for(Sphere s : mSpheres) {
        s.draw(canvas);
    }

    invalidate();
}
```

and the problem occurs in flowPhysics(boolean) method, at this line:

```
for(int i=0; i < mSpheres.size(); ++i) {
            for(int j=i+1; j < mSpheres.size(); ++j) {

                Sphere a = mSpheres.get(i);
                Sphere b = mSpheres.get(j);

                if(advancedSphereSphere(a, b) || step) {
                    if(timeToCollision < dt && !step) {
                        flowPhysics(true);
                    }

                    if(step) {
                        sphereCollisionResponse(a, b);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

When the advancedSphereSphere() is called, the first Sphere disappears, I checked and noticed that the problem is in that method at the first line:

```
Vector2D s = a.getPos().sub(b.getPos());
```

if I put something else here and don't subtract the b from a vectors, it draws the balls (but no collision occurs). The Java code above is mostly ported code from here: http://wp.freya.no/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=Public&path=%2Fopengl%2Fcollisiondetect%2Fcollisiondetect.cpp

Can u give me an idea on what is the problem?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
private void sphereCollisionResponse(Sphere a, Sphere b)
    {
        double m1, m2, x1, x2;
        Vector2D v1, v2, v1x, v2x, v1y, v2y;
        Vector2D x = new Vector2D(a.getPos().sub(b.getPos()));

        x.normalize();
        v1 = new Vector2D(a.getVelocity());
        x1 = x.dot(v1);
        v1x = new Vector2D(x.multiply(x1));
        v1y = new Vector2D(v1.sub(v1x));
        m1 = a.getMass();

        x = new Vector2D(x.multiply(-1));
        v2 = new Vector2D(b.getVelocity());
        x2 = x.dot(v2);
        v2x = new Vector2D(x.multiply(x2));
        v2y = new Vector2D(v2.sub(v2x));
        m2 = b.getMass();

        Vector2D nn = new Vector2D(v1x.multiply(m1-m2));
        Vector2D mm = new Vector2D(nn.divide(m1+m2));
        Vector2D tt = new Vector2D(v2x.multiply(2*m2));
        Vector2D rr = new Vector2D(tt.divide(m1+m2));
        Vector2D gg = new Vector2D(mm.add(rr));
        Vector2D ss = new Vector2D(gg.add(v1y));

        Vector2D nva = ss; 
        a.setVelocity(nva);

        Vector2D nvb = new Vector2D(v1x.multiply(2*m1).divide(m1+m2).add(v2x.multiply(m2-m2).divide(m1+m2).add(v2y)));
        b.setVelocity(nvb);     
}
```

Comment: "the first Sphere disappears" - is that because your system thinks it collided with itself? What do `doPhysics` and `sphereCollisionResponse` do?

Comment: Where is `step` defined?  How is it defined?

Comment: step is parameter in flowPhysics(boolean step), just as helper for the recursion to work. (in onDraw as you can see, I have flowPhysics(false) and then I have recursion in flowPhysics() itself where If collision occurs I set it to true (flowPhysics(true)).

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is really in this line

```
Vector2D s = a.getPos().sub(b.getPos());
```

then I suspect the problem may lie in your `Vector2D` class. You should check that the `sub` method just returns a new `Vector2D` and does not modify the coordinates of the original vector `a`. Keeping your objects immutable as far as possible makes them safer to use.

Failing that, the answer is [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). Learning to use [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) or [TestNG](http://testng.org/) will pay off in the long run, but even a few ad-hoc print statements might help you for now. You should be able to check the mathematics is correct independent of how the spheres appear on your screen, and doing this consistently will probably guide you towards a clearer design.

Just by testing that the position of each sphere is unchanged after the collision, and that the velocities are as expected in a few simple cases, you are quite likely to discover the bug in your code. For example, if both velocities are zero beforehand then they should be zero afterwards. If the collision is elastic and one sphere (A) collides head-on with another stationary sphere (B), sphere A should be stationary afterwards and sphere B should have the velocity that A started with.

I haven't checked the maths in your code at http://pastie.org/2499691 but when I set up a few simple classes to fill the dependencies and give it some reasonable starting conditions, it doesn't conserve momentum, so I can believe for some values the balls could end up flying off the screen at the speed of light.

Once you have the physics right, you can work on any remaining problems with the display of the spheres secure in the knowledge that the problem must indeed lie there.

Comment: Hi. there was a bug in the sub() method - yes. But then again, the collision works great, then the response is not working. Can you check this code for the response: http://pastie.org/2499691 - I use this Vector2D class: http://goo.gl/I4R4Y. When the balls collide - the first one (a) - disappears :(

Comment: I'll check your code later, but after a quick look at Vector2D I think you want subtract() not sub() to avoid modifying the original vector. Your ball could then be leaping to some off-screen position, which might make it seem to disappear.

Comment: Yes - I changed to subtract - and it still jumps off my scren :(